# Why are BigInteger calculations faster than any other primitive used calculations in JAVA

Tags: java, performance

For large numbers what algorithm is followed by BigIntegers to give results in really quick time?
Ex- finding factorials or finding huge exponents

Comment: paste some benchmarking code

Comment: If you want to understand Algorithms I recommend reading this [Analysis of Algorithms](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/djimenez/utsa/cs3343/lecture20.html)

Comment: FYI (because of your title) BigInteger is _not_ a primitive.

Comment: What algorithm...for what? BigInteger does a whole lot of stuff, you know.

Comment: [The source code is available online](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java) so you can just go look at it.

Comment: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/math/BigInteger.java.html

Look at the code..and find for yourself

Comment: I'm highly suspicious of this claim.

Comment: Please upvote this question, or else I can't get the bronze badge for maintaining a positive question record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find out how `BigInteger` works under the covers ... read [the source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/math/BigInteger.java.html).  (It is easy to find the Java source code on the web with Google.)

If you are looking for fast algorithms that you can use (with `BigInteger`) to "find factorials" or "find exponents", I suggest that you start by looking on Wikipedia ... which often has information on computational algorithms of that nature.  If that fails, try Google.

---

> Why are BigInteger calculations faster than any other primitive used calculations in JAVA

They are not faster.  In fact `BigInteger` are typically *orders of magnitude slower* than analogous calculations done using the primitive integer types; i.e. `byte`, `short`, `char`, `int` and `long`.   (Of course the calculations are typically not equivalent ... because of the representation limitations of the primitive types, compared to `BigInteger`.)

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard a claim that BigInteger is faster than any of the primitive types. It can handle "infinite precision", and thus can process large numbers without the oddities of floating-point roundoff, and thus it is sometimes suggested for computations such as factorials which grow very large very quickly. But that's *despite* its performance characteristics, not because of of them.